# How can I change the date format in Java?

Tags: java, date

I need to change the date format using Java from

```
 dd/MM/yyyy  to yyyy/MM/dd
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

How to convert from one date format to another using [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
final String OLD_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";
final String NEW_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd";

// August 12, 2010
String oldDateString = "12/08/2010";
String newDateString;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
newDateString = sdf.format(d);
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: "Sdf" counds weird to me, because in French it means "homeless person". Yet, thanks for this solution :p

Answer (score 32):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
sdf.format(new Date());
```

This should do the trick

Comment: i have an string in `dd/MM/yyyy ` format how can i convert

Answer (score 26):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "23/01/2017" ,  
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" , Locale.UK ) 
).format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu/MM/dd" , Locale.UK )
)
```

> 2017/01/23

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The [answer by Christopher Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469715/642706) is correct but outdated. The troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## Using java.time

Parse the input string as a date-time object, then generate a new String object in the desired format.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter fIn = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" , Locale.UK );  // As a habit, specify the desired/expected locale, though in this case the locale is irrelevant.
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "23/01/2017" , fIn );
```

Define another formatter for the output.

```
DateTimeFormatter fOut = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu/MM/dd" , Locale.UK );
String output = ld.format( fOut );
```

> 2017/01/23

By the way, consider using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for strings representing date-time values.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. This section here is left for the sake of history.

For fun, here is his code adapted for using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

final String OLD_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";
final String NEW_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd";

// August 12, 2010
String oldDateString = "12/08/2010";
String newDateString;

DateTimeFormatter formatterOld = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(OLD_FORMAT);
DateTimeFormatter formatterNew = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
LocalDate localDate = formatterOld.parseLocalDate( oldDateString );
newDateString = formatterNew.print( localDate );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "localDate: " + localDate );
System.out.println( "newDateString: " + newDateString );
```

When run…

```
localDate: 2010-08-12
newDateString: 2010/08/12
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
    String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    System.out.println("Formated Date " + sdf.format(date));
```

Complete Example:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class JavaSimpleDateFormatExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Create Date object.
        Date date = new Date();
        // Specify the desired date format
        String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd";
        // Create object of SimpleDateFormat and pass the desired date format.
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        /*
         * Use format method of SimpleDateFormat class to format the date.
         */
        System.out.println("Today is " + sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

Comment: can i pass an string to date??

Answer (score 4):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date myDate = sdf.parse("28/12/2013");
sdf.applyPattern("yyyy/MM/dd")
String myDateString = sdf.format(myDate);
```

Now myDateString = 2013/12/28

Answer (score 4):

This is just Christopher Parker's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469715/85421) adapted to use the new<sup>1</sup> classes from Java 8:

```
final DateTimeFormatter OLD_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
final DateTimeFormatter NEW_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

String oldString = "26/07/2017";
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(oldString, OLD_FORMATTER);
String newString = date.format(NEW_FORMATTER);
```

1 well, not that new anymore, Java 9 should be released soon.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could go the regex route:

```
String date = "10/07/2010";
String newDate = date.replaceAll("(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)", "$3/$2/$1");
System.out.println(newDate);
```

It works both ways too. Of course this won't actually validate your date and will also work for strings like "21432/32423/52352". You can use `"(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4}"` to be more exact in the number of digits in each group, but it will only work from dd/MM/yyyy to yyyy/MM/dd and not the other way around anymore (and still accepts invalid numbers in there like 45). And if you give it something invalid like "blabla" it will just return the same thing back.

Comment: Now you have two problems. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for being so clear about the limitations of your approach.

Answer (score 1):

many ways to change date format

```
private final String dateTimeFormatPattern = "yyyy/MM/dd";
private final Date now = new Date();  

final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormatPattern);  
final String nowString = format.format(now);   

 final Instant instant = now.toInstant();  
 final DateTimeFormatter formatter =  
      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(  
         dateTimeFormatPattern).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());  
 final String formattedInstance = formatter.format(instant);  

  /* Java 8 needed*/
  LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
  String text = date.format(formatter);
  LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
```

Answer (score 1):

To Change the format of Date you have Require both format look below.

```
 String stringdate1 = "28/04/2010";  

 try {

     SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     Date date1 = format1.parse()
     SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

     String stringdate2 = format2.format(date1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

here `stringdate2` have date format of `yyyy/MM/dd`. and it contain `2010/04/28`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
System.out.println(format1.format(date));
```