# How to format this string do a proper date format?

Tags: java, date

I'm very new to Java programming and I have string like this:

```
2013-03-15T07:23:13Z
```

I wish I could convert this into date format like:

```
15-03-2013
```

is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Take the reference to this link

[How can I change the date format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java)

See the answer given by Mr. Christopher Parker

It has explained all your needs and it will provide you the easiest solution which is logically correct

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
try {
    DateFormat sourceDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    String strSourceDate = "2013-03-15T07:23:13Z";
    Date targetDate = (Date) sourceDateFormat.parseObject(strSourceDate);
    String strTargetDate = targetFormat.format(targetDate);
    System.out.println(strTargetDate);

} catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the input string is fixed, the simplest and the most expedient way of doing this would be with string manipulation:

```
String s = "2013-03-15T07:23:13Z";
String res = s.substring(8, 10)+"-"+s.substring(5, 7)+"-"+s.substring(0, 4);
```

It would spare you dealing with dates and calendars. Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/JmScTn).

Comment: @user2164685 There is no such thing as "the" appropriate way, only "an" appropriate one. What's the most appropriate is not up to us to decide, only the OP knows that judging from the overall requirements of his or her application.

Comment: @Fahim Parkar that is what I am saying.This method is not correct

Comment: @FahimParkar Right: SDF may be a lot more than the OP needs. But then again, maybe not.

Comment: @user2164685 : though it is not appropriate way, but why to get confused in SDF when we are getting with this... :) :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : I would use this trick (if I don't want proper structured date). seriously. :) :D

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No objection

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Date dNow = new Date( );
  SimpleDateFormat ft = 
  new SimpleDateFormat ("dd.MM.yyyy");

  System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));
```

It's output

```
 Current Date: 15.03.2013
```

Comment: but instead of dNow, you should consider OP date.

Comment: LOL!!! I don't meant to change variable name. I meant `Date myDate = OP Input` and not `new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

`java.text.SimpleDateFormat` is what you need: [SimpleDateFormat JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

You'll need one format to convert your input `String` into a `Date` using the `parse()` method, and then another to convert that `Date` into a `String` in your desired format using `format()`.

If your application could be used internationally, don't forget to think about correctly localizing the output of the second function though.  03-11-2013 is March 11th in some countries, November 3rd in others.

Answer (score 0):

Using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
    String strDate = "2013-03-15T07:23:13Z";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String date = dateFormat.format(strDate);
    System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yyyy format : " + date);
```

Hope it help you...