# throws an exception which says unparseable format

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I need to fetch a date from database and convert it to util date...

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dob = rst.getString("dob");
java.util.Date DateTemp = new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse(dob).getTime());
```

But it throws an exception which says `unparseable format`.

Comment: Print dob so you know what it is

Comment: What is your given date format ? I mean the value of "rst.getString("dob")" . Due to this it throws the excetpion

Comment: Adding to others comment , why do you store the date as string , you can go for date related datatypes in DB !

Comment: In database is stored as yyyy/MM/dd(for e.g. 2013/11/28), and i need to use it in application as dd/MM/yyyy(for e.g 28/11/2013)

Comment: That's a different question then...why wouldn't you put that in the opening post?

Comment: If the format of the date won't change, better format the date as text in the database query and then just read a string. (TO_CHAR, CONVERT or something - depending on the SQL Dialect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to answer your question in a simple manner.  Your `dob` value isn't the correct format.  The `formatter.parse(dob)` isn't working because it can't parse (or attempting to extract and change the data to the appropriate format).

Now to change format (from DB format to application format):

```
final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd";
final String NEW_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";

String oldDateString = rst.getString("dob").replaceAll("-","/");//you to need to replace all the all dashes with slashes
String newDateString;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
newDateString = sdf.format(d);
```

Source:

[How can I change the date format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java)

Comment: Still the same exception, but i you have delivered the 99% what i want. I am just short of 1%...

Comment: Did you print the "dob" varaiable?  Can you post the results here?

Comment: Also, can you post the entire error/exception message (and let me know which line it the problem roots from)?

Comment: I just noticed, are you still using "formatter.parse(dob).getTime()"?  Try just with "formatter.parse(dob)", then see what happens.  If no time exists, then I don't know how it will get it.

Comment: No i print newDateString

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1977-07-06"

Comment: I copied your code and paste it, i haven't used formatter.parse(dob).getTime.....

Comment: I made a change to my code above.  You can't have the dashes in the date.  You need to put "/".

Comment: ok i check it, and thanks for keeping patience on this particular problem, i owe you.

Comment: Get me an escort for a night, and I'll call it even.

Comment: Ha ha.. It was solved.. Thanks a lot, I cant figure it out of my own, Thanks Man...

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `ResultSet.getDate` instead, it returns `java.sql.Date` which exte nds `java.util.Date` so you can use it where `java.util.Date` is requried.

As for the ParseException: ResultSet.getString for DATE column returns date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, you should have parsed it with this format.

Answer (score 1):

> In database is stored as yyyy/MM/dd(for e.g. 2013/11/28), and i need to use it in application as dd/MM/yyyy(for e.g 28/11/2013)

Then your first formatter while parsing the string to date should be `yyyy/MM/dd` and then to format the date object to string should be `dd/MM/yyyy` !

Moreover , there are appropriate datatypes[DATE,DATETIME etc] to store dates in DB tables , don't use string[CHAR,VARCHAR].