# How to format a timestamp in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-date

I'm new in android how do I format this `"2013-07-02T04:17:24Z"` into 
`July 02, 2013 12:00 PM`

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** 
Here is my code. Is there anything wrong in my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
String formattedDate1 = sdf1.format("2013-07-02T04:17:24Z");
```

Comment: Try to google first before posting question , you can use [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Comment: I'd googled it... and follow their examples but no luck.. That's why I ask here to get some help on how to parse/format a date in android

Comment: try `sdf1.format(new Date());` format method for [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) accepts Date object. please refer to [API DOC](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the same. It does what you want and a sample example is also given in the documentation. Try something like below. You might have to change the variables values `OLD_FORMAT` and `NEW_FORMAT` as per your requirements. You can see the meaning of the symbols on above link.

```
final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
final String NEW_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a";

String oldDateString = "2013-07-02T04:17:24Z";
String newDateString;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
newDateString = sdf.format(d);
```

I took the help from answers on [How can I change the date format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java) question as well. You may see the link for more.

Comment: Having error 

`W/System.err(12406): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-07-02T04:17:24Z" (at offset 19)`

Comment: As I said in the answer, that the code provides you the way to parse one format to other. You might need to change the `OLD_FORMAT`, i.e the pattern of Date and Time which you are expecting to convert. Use the link I gave(http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to further check for the appropriate pattern for the input date format. There is a whole list of all the available options, which you can use for parsing a Date format.