# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in Android with DateFormat

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

Here is my code fragment

here date in 10-Sep-2013 09:53:37 format

```
TextView tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.entered_date);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
tvDate.setText(dateFormat.format(salesReportItems.getDate().toString()));
TextView tvCardType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_type);
tvCardType.setText(salesReportItems.getCardType().toString());
```

Please help me to sort out this issue.here is my error.
[image]

Dear Piyush,

Here is out put when i used your code

[image]

Comment: What is the value for `salesReportItems.getDate().toString()`

Comment: Ok. See my added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method like below

```
private String formatDate(String dateString) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" /* 10-Sep-2013 09:53:37*/);
            Date d = sd.parse(dateString);
            sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            return sd.format(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
        return "";
    }
```

And then call it as

```
tvDate.setText(formatDate(salesReportItems.getDate().toString()));
```

---

Read more about [How can I change the date format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use your code like this..

if `salesReportItems` is `Date` type object then..

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    .format(salesReportItems);
tvDate.setText(timeStamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that this line

```
tvDate.setText(dateFormat.format(salesReportItems.getDate().toString()));
```

needs to be like this.

```
tvDate.setText(dateFormat.format(salesReportItems.getDate()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.entered_date);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Remove your third line ,
 get the date as string,

```
String date=salesReportItems.getDate().toString();
```

use `System.out.println(date);` to date get displayed in Logcat;

from the observed date form string in pattern like this;

```
sring str="1990-08-27";
```

then use,

```
tvDate.setText(dateFormat.format(str));
```

instead of dateFormat.format use dateFormat.parse(str);

Comment: instead use dateFormat.parse(str);

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
Date d = sd.parse(salesReportItems.getDate().toString());
sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
TextView tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.entered_date);
tvDate.setText(sd.format(d));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Issue sorted with above code.