# How to convert text formdata from jsp to date inside an servlet?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp file to get data via form, and passing it to a servlet.

```
<form action="RegistrationProcessing" method="get">
Date of Birth:<input type="text" name="dob">
</form>
```

This is the servlet file

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws   ServletException, IOException {
String dateofbirth=request.getParameter("dob");
}
```

I can't change the datatype of dateofbirth variable. It is saying it must be only string, what should i do now to store it as different datatype.I want to store in oracle database where the date format is '01-JAN-2013' , how can i parse to this datatype.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i change the date format in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert `String` to `date`.Then use `java.sql.Date` to store it in Database

example

```
String DateStr="2013-10-31T19:00:00Z";// date String 
    SimpleDateFormat sim=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(DateStr); //converted String to date in the desired format

    java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());//formatted to java.sql.date format to store in database
```

Comment: I successfully parsed to that format , but i want to store in oracle database where the date format is '01-JAN-2013' , how can i parse to this datatype.

Comment: @SatheshBm update your question with your reuirement and I will also update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat()` to convert String to Date object.

Do like below.

```
  java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("20131105");

  java.sql.Date sqlDate= new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy").parse(dateofbirth);
```

You will have to change the "`MMddyyyy`" format string to fit your dates format.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get datetype directly,but you can convert a String format date data to a Date format date data.