# Getting current Date and saving it in database

Tags: java, mysql, date

How do I get the current date with the format of `yyyy-MM-dd` and save it in database with `Date` value? I have this code but it does not work...

Java:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
d.setMonth(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
d.setDate(cal.get(Calendar.DATE)-1900);
d.setYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Here is my PreparedStatement:

```
pstmt.setDate(6, (Date)d);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `java.sql.Date` instance to set to database column.

Convert the `java.util.Date` instance to `java.sql.Date`.

You can also use `Calander` instance to convert.

**Change**:

```
pstmt.setDate( 6, (Date)d );
```

**To**:

```
pstmt.setDate( 6, new java.sql.Date( d.getTime() ) );
```

**OR To**:

```
pstmt.setDate( 6, new java.sql.Date( cal.getTimeInMillis() ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println("Current Date : "+dateFormat.format(date));
```

using insert query you can save this date object to database.

Answer (score 0):

```
    long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy     hh:mm:ss a");
    String date=dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime());
    return date;
```