# Mule - Date format from m/dd/yy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: date, mule, datamapper

want to convert date to the above required format. Is it possible to write a groovy script to do so in datamapper? If yes can you please give an example. Or can i reference another expression or component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do what you need is to edit the datamapper script and replace the line where you perform the date mapping for this one:

```
output.date = date2str(str2date(input.date,"d/mm/yy"), "yyyy-mm-dd");
```

but replacing the input and output fields accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java) which explains how to do it in java. You may easily groovify it.

Here the script

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def OLD_FORMAT = "m/dd/yy"
def NEW_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd"
// August 12, 2010
def oldDateString = "8/12/10"
def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT)
def d = sdf.parse(oldDateString)
sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT)
newDateString = sdf.format(d)
println "Date in modified format : $newDateString"
```

EDIT:
Changed as per source format based on comment

Answer (score 0):

You can also use format method in the expression to set the date as below :

```
flowVars.Timestamp = server.dateTime.format("YYYYMMDDHHmm");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#[server.dateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd')]
```

Comment: Please add some description/explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of such nesting.

I prefer a variation on the above answers, where I only keep the inner function:

```
output.date = str2date(input.date,"m/dd/yy")
```

but then defined the output format in the datamapper's graphical editor, by setting the field to a date with format "yyyy-MM-dd".

Both of these approaches work, but I find this method easier to read and far easier to explain to others.