# customising the date format in java to be in specific order

Tags: java

I have the following string variables in which dates are stored in format of dd/mm/yy that is UK format

```
String s= "04-MAR-15"
String t ="04/03/15"
String p ="04/03/2015"
String w ="04-03-2015"
```

now i want to convert their format in DD/MM/YYYY format,
 please advise how can I convert their format through simple date format in java and show on console.

Comment: Do some analysis before posting a question. There are tons of examples in internet

Comment: @Raheman agree with you there are more examples of simple date format in java

Comment: @Rehman you can mark it a duplicate..in which you will require some analysis too.. instead of rudely saying something..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the date format in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The process is a two step process:

- Convert the `String` to a `Date` using the `parse` method of `DateFormat`
- Convert the `Date` to the new `String` using the method format of a  `DateFormat` with the desired format

Use the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) concrete class. See the documentation to understand the desired pattern.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

## Try parsing with each expected format

When you have inputs of various formats, if those formats are mutually exclusive (not ambiguous for one another), simply try parsing each known possible format until one works. When a parsing attempt fails, catch the Exception thrown and try parsing with the next format.

For more information on parsing a string into a date-only object, see [How can I change the date format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3469507/642706) and many other posts already made on Stack Overflow. Here's a brief example of code.

First, define and collect a series of formatters for each expected format.

```
Locale locale = Locale.UK ;
List<DateTimeFormatter> formatters = new ArrayList<>( 4 );
formatters.add( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu" , locale ) ) ;
formatters.add( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uu" , locale ) ) ;
formatters.add( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" , locale ) ) ;
formatters.add( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" , locale ) ) ;
```

Try each formatter successively until one succeeds.

```
LocalDate ld = null ;
for( DateTimeFormatter f : formatters ) {
    try{
        ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
        break ; // End this 'for' loop. We succeeded in parsing, so no need to try more formatters. 
    } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
        // Swallow this exception as we expect it when trying a series of formatters.
    }
}
```

Test to see if all the formatters failed to parse. This means we received an input of unexpected format, an error situation.

```
if( null == ld ) {  // All the formatters were tried but failed.
    … // Deal with unexpected input.
}
```

Generate a new String as your output using `DateTimeFormatter`. Consider using the `ofLocalized…` method rather than specify a particular format.

## ISO 8601

Personally, I recommend against ever using a two-digit year. That causes no end of confusion being ambiguous with the month and day-of-month. Memory is cheap enough, and screens big enough, that we can easily afford the bits and pixels to support the luxury of 4-digit years.

Also, consider avoiding your patterns entirely. For data exchange, use only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. For a date only that would be YYYY-MM-DD such as `2017-01-23`.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).