# how to convert String ("1-DEC-16") and ("01-DEC-16") to java Date as 01-DEC-2016

Tags: java

I have CSV data to import into data base where I have date column in that CSV in that some dates are like `1-DEC-16` without a leading zero (padding zero). How to make that String as `01-DEC-2016`? Can it be done with  SimpleDateFormat or is there any String format method? I tried with below but it’s not happening.

```
String d="1-DEC-17";

String newstring = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(d);
System.out.println(newstring);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the date format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java)

Comment: even that SimpleDateFormat#format(d); takes an object as parameter, the operation is invalid with strings....

Comment: you should: String  →  Date → Formatted_String

Comment: A `SimpleDateFormat` can convert a `String` to a `Date` or a `Date` to a `String`, but you shouldn't use it to convert a `String` to a `String`.

Comment: ok thank you for the info, i want convert     1-Dec-16 to java date as   01-DEC-2017 how to give formate?

Comment: @bharathRaj Is the Shift key broken on your keyboard? I cleaned that up for you on this Question, while adding some other text for search optimization. But try to get that key fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

## `d` vs `dd`

To parse a string with a leading zero on the month or day-of-month, use a pair of formatting pattern characters. That would be `dd` for day-of-month.

To parse a string without a leading zero, use a single character, `d` for day-of-month.

Unfortunately, your input has the month name abbreviation in all uppercase. That violates the norm of the English-speaking locales I know of, such as `Locale.US`. So by default, a `DateTimeFormatter` will refuse to process that improper input. To tolerate the all-uppercase, we can set the formatter to be “lenient”.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d-MMM-uu" , Locale.US ).withResolverStyle( ResolverStyle.LENIENT )  ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "1-DEC-17" , f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/LrBhgz).

> ld.toString(): 2017-12-01

If sending this value to a database, do not use a string for date-time value. Use a date-time object for date-time values.

For JDBC drivers compliant with JDBC 4.2 and later, pass the java.time types directly via `setObject` & `getObject`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

If not compliant, convert briefly to the troublesome old legacy type, `java.sql.Date`. Use the new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Date d = java.sql.Date.valueOf( ld ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setDate( … , d ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).