# I am getting date from calendar in UI in the format as dd/mm/yyyy. But i want it in 12-Jul-18 format

Tags: java, date, jsp

I am getting date from calendar in UI in the format as dd/mm/yyyy. But i am unable to save it in that format as I need date value as 22-Jul-18. Is there any simple way I can get the data in jsp as 22-July-18 format directly. Though I can use enum and may be do some modifications in my coding to change it.
But it will be very helpful if anyone can help me with this . Thanks in advance.

Comment: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) should be helpful for the work

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: If you are saving to a database, use the database’s `date` type and avoid saving as a string. If you do need to save as a string (for example in a text file), it’s recommended to use the ISO 8601 standard format: `2018-07-22`. Of course, if your format cannot be changed, you need to go with it (and cross your fingers that you don’t get year 2000 problems or code that fails when run on a computer with a non-English locale).

Comment: You need to show the code you're working with. Preferably a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried but it was giving error as Cannot format given Object as Date. I am using Oracle and in my table the data type is DATE. And in my entity class it is of String type. Also i tried to change the data type of my date field in my hibernate entity class as Date(java.util.Date) from String. But then I am getting error in my UI as Bad request amd no error in console.

Comment: `LocalDate.parse("22/07/2018", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uu", Locale.ROOT))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.US).format(new Date());
System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

```
26-Jun-18
```

PS: as @Ole V.V. already mentioned it is outdated approach to get it with `SimpleDateFormat`. Instead you can use this sample:

```
import java.time.*; 

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
String formatDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);
System.out.println(formatDateTime);
```

Output:

```
26-Jun-18
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the Calendar for, rather than just new Date() ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, now is more elegant, thank you for pointing it ))

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Come to think of it, sorry that I was nitpicking about creating a Date directly when there are more direct issues: The month is wanted in short form, so it should be 3 Ms instead of 4. And to represent the year you need lowercase ys. An uppercase Y represents "week year", that is to say, the year of the week of the specified date. Remember weeks are sequences of 7 days, and they tend to overlap between two years. One of these two years is the one that the week "belongs" to. Uppercase Y represents that year. It's incorrect. You need lowercase y, the year the current date is in.

Comment: @OleV.V. thank you for the comment, I have added also the example with `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: @kumesana I have edited an answer, I have had MMMM beacuse of `Is there any simple way I can get the data in jsp as 22-July-18 format directly`. For YY and yy thank you very much!

Comment: I am learning and trying to build a small application using JSP, Spring and hibernate. In this application I made a jsp page where I am getting event name, event date etc. So, in UI from calender I am selecting  the date.

Comment: Thx. Since the asker’s date doesn’t have time of day `LocalDate` is a better choice than `LocalDateTime` (that the modern API has so relatively many types is both its strength and its challenge when learning to use it).

Comment: @Ole Thank you. It works But issue is it takes current local date and work fine. When I am selecting future date for the event and passing in a string. How can i do that?

Comment: @Mani I have added an original concerned with a date without time of day as you. The format is not the same — can you modify the solution to fit your situation? I particularly recommend the two answers using `java.time`: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20821770/5772882) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331724/5772882). To get the month as abbreviation you need three `M`s, `MMM` and you need to specify locale.

Comment: See also [my comment under your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51037315/i-am-getting-date-from-calendar-in-ui-in-the-format-as-dd-mm-yyyy-but-i-want-it#comment89068358_51037315).

Comment: @Ole Thank you so much for your help. My code is working perfectly now. Also, thank you all other folks for all your suggestions.