# how to convert date from 31-AUG-18 to AUGUST31,2018 in Java

Tags: java, date-formatting, date-parsing, date

I'm getting a date as input in the format of 31-AUG-2018. I would like to convert it into AUGUST31,2018 using java

Comment: I guess you just tried doing it after googling for that. Perhaps you can provide some code that does not work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the date format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java)

Comment: @JoeC Not a duplicate as this Question here involves the issue of localized Month name, with further complication of being all-uppercase. Likely this *is* a duplicate but not of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing text.

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = 
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)
;

DateTimeFormatter outputformatter =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMMdd,uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH)
;

String input = "31-AUG-2018";
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(input, inputFormatter);
```

Generating text.

```
String output = date.format(outputformatter).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

System.out.println("Converted to: " + output);
```

This snippet outputs:

> Converted to: AUGUST31,2018

The all caps in both input and output require a bit of special treatment. For the input I am using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `parseCaseInsensitive` method. This gives a formatter that will parse the month abbreviation in uppercase or lowercase or any mix of them. For the output I saw no better option than calling `toUpperCase` on the result.