# Date format convertion form Month dd, yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in java

Tags: java

How do i convert the below date:

Apr 29, 2022 to 04/29/20222

So basically my input date  in format Mon dd, yyyy should be converted to mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: but prefer the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20821770/16320675) to that question, using the newer `java.time.LocalDate`

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html)

```
String date = "Apr 29, 2022";
DateTimeFormatter fromFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy")
         .withLocale(Locale.US);
DateTimeFormatter toFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date,fromFormat);
System.out.println(localDate.format(toFormat));
```

prints

```
04/29/2022
```

For other useful date/time processing classes check out the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.